# Как получить 4 популярных цвета?

Tags: laravel

**Controller**

```
class YarnController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $yarns = Yarn::where('status', 1)
                     ->has('colors')
                     ->orderBy('contacts', 'desc')
                     ->get();

        return view('yarn.index', compact('yarns'));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Yarn extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['colors'];

    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(YarnColor::class)
                    ->where('status', 1)
                    ->orderBy('contacts', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Как получить 4 самых популярных цвета, а не все (как сейчас)?

Comment: я этот птичий язык не знаю, но, по сути, отсортируйте по популярности по убыванию и скажите limit 4

Comment: Ограничьте выборку релейшена `Yarn::with(['colors' => fn ($query) => $query->limit(4)])->has('colors')->orderBy***`

Comment: @Walfter написано, что нельзя так https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Попробуйте через скопу, либо добавьте новый релейт который будет доставать 4 записи

Comment: @Walfter пробивал